# Optimal memory trace for a DAG of dependency evaluations

Tags: algorithm, memory, graph, compiler-optimization, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm looking for an algorithm which to optimise the order of evaluations on a DAG, such that least memory is used. It might be a bit harder to explain, so I'll give an example what I mean. Consider that you have a DAG with multiple roots, which represents some form of dependency evaluation order. So each child node can perform its action only after its parents have performed. Additionally, we can release from memory each node which we do not need any more. The task is to find the optimal sequential schedule of evaluation such that least memory is used at any time. For instance consider the graph below:

[image: Evaluation Graph]

And the two schedules:

```
load A - 1 node in memory
load B - 2 
eval C - 3
eval D - 4
eval F - 5
unload C - 4
eval H - 5
unload A,F - 3
eval E - 4
eval G - 5
unload D,E - 3
eval I - 4
unload B,G - 2
eval J - 3
unload H,I

Maximum memory trace - 5
```

And this one:

```
load A - 1 node in memory
load B - 2 
eval C - 3
eval D - 4
eval E - 5
eval F - 6
unload C - 5
eval G - 6
unload D,E - 4
eval H - 5
unload A,F - 3
eval I - 4
unload B,G - 2
eval J - 3
unload H,I - 1
unload C - 4
eval H - 5
unload A,F - 3
eval E - 4
eval G - 5
unload D,E - 3
eval I - 4
unload B,G - 2
eval J - 3
unload H,I

Maximum memory trace - 6
```

Assuming that all nodes occupy same memory, is there an algorithm which does this optimally? The first one is sort of like a Depth First traversal, while the second one is like Breath First traversal, but I'm not aware if those are optimal and why.

**PS:**

Just to clarify, as @Evgeny Kluev pointed out in his comment, this is very similar to Register Allocation, which can be solved using heuristic greedy graph colouring algorithms efficiently. However, register allocation is a simpler problem, since it assumes that you know the order of computation and thus can calculate the liveness of each variable. After this you can easily build the Inference graph and do the graph colouring. In our case we want to that **as well as** optimise the order of computation. This of course requires some assumptions, such as that we have no pointers and only basic data structures (which is what my Nodes represent). Obviously, since graph colouring is NP-complete, than this problem is at least NP-complete. What I'm looking for is for some sort of greedy/heuristic algorithm which to give a good solution on some not too degenerate cases.

Comment: Maybe invert the direction of the arrows? New meaning: J must come after I and H.

Comment: Yes but still because each node can have more than 1 parent, it matters what is the order. In the more complicate cases you can have whole sub trees on left and right. When you have 2 parents which one of the parents should be first and so on. Need a systematic way to do this. Just reversing the arrows does not give you ordering.

Comment: @Belov do you have a memory limit or you want to do this optimally? because I know a solution for the memory limit version.

Comment: @Belov if you use BFS, then the nodes in you memory cannot be smaller than your branch factor, and if you use DFS, this number cannot be smaller than the longest route from root to a leave. so its a matter of choice as your needs go.

Comment: This problem is very similar to [Register allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation) and may be solved by graph coloring algorithms.

Comment: Is is possible to 'load' node multiple times?

Comment: mm theoretically yes, but practically no, because that would require writing to disk, which obviously gona slow things tremendously. Also if you are doing this on a GPU you know what it means...

Comment: @EvgenyKluev, that is correct that the problem is similar, but not exactly. The register allocation problem is in fact a simplified version of this, since there you already have a predefined schedule of evaluation, thus you do have all of the lifetimes of each variables, and you can build the so called Inference graph and do the colouring. However here we are doing the same + we need to find the optimal order of evaluation, given there is no pointers or higher order structures.

Comment: BTW: approximately how many nodes are there ? And how many can be loaded at the same moment?

Comment: Well, that is sort of different every time (which is why I need an algo rather than hard coding it). How many can be loaded also depends. The number of nodes is approximately in the values 100-1000. As to how many can be loaded at one time it also is not a hard thing but lets say 30-50. Both of does are varying really, can't give a straight answer.

Comment: Is there an actual diffrence between eval and load? Because it's kinda confusing (I mean, you load A, but you don't evaluate it, and you evaluate C without having it loaded)...

Comment: Can the memory used by a parent be reused by its children at its evaluation if the parent is not longer needed?

Comment: @AlexBotev - did you successfully use Crisp, or some other algorithm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, in some sense this problem is easier than the graph coloring problem, because *the decision version* of this problem is a special case of the decision version of the [Combined Register Allocation and Instruction Scheduling Problem (CRISP)](http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tn/95/22/CS-TN-95-22.pdf), which is simpler to solve than the graph coloring problem (at least when the exact solution is not required).

The decision version of this problem can be formulated as Whether a schedule using at most *m* memory slots exists?

### Reduction to CRISP

Please note, that below I will use the terminology from the referenced article.

For each node *v* in your problem let's introduce *virtual* register *r<sub>v</sub>* and instruction *x<sub>v</sub>* in CRISP, the instruction writes to register *r<sub>v</sub>* and reads each register *r<sub>u</sub>* corresponding to parent node *u* of node *v*. Also, for each edge (*u*, *v*) of the *DAG* we introduce edge (*x<sub>u</sub>*, *x<sub>v</sub>*) in the dependency graph of CRISP. The execution time of each instruction equals to 1, the latency of each dependency edge equals to 0, and the spill cost equals to ∞. The number of available *physical* registers equals to *m*.

If there is a schedule in CRISP of the time length at most the number of nodes, then there is the corresponding schedule in the original problem that uses at most *m* memory slots. We are done.

### If Memory Used by Parent Cannot Be Reused by Children

The reduction presented above assumes that the memory used by a parent can be reused by the children when the parent is no longer needed. When it is not allowed, the following modifications are required:

Add one more instruction, *y<sub>v</sub>*, for each node *v*. Now, *x<sub>v</sub>* only writes *r<sub>v</sub>*, and *y<sub>v</sub>* reads each *r<sub>u</sub>* corresponding to parent *u*. Add dependency graph edge (*x<sub>v</sub>*, *y<sub>v</sub>*). Set the execution time of each instruction to 0.5. That's all.

Note that separation of register writing and reading between different instructions is required in order to prevent reuse of parent registers when it is not allowed.

### Algorithm

The article referenced in the beginning describes an efficient algorithm to solve CRISP approximately. It can be used to solve this problem as well — just use the reduction above and try every *m* starting from 1 until a solution is found.

Notice also, that the algorithm is parameterized by two parameters: α and β, where α is the weight for controlling register pressure and β is the weight for controlling instruction parallelism. For this problem set α to 1 and β to 0, as the instruction parallelism is not needed for this problem.

Comment: God bless you! That was exactly what I was looking for and indeed it is simpler, although not so obvious at first (as I thought).